# Python Unicode error when printing variable

Tags: python, unicode

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import testapi.api
import testapi.ladder.analytics

if not len(sys.argv) == 2:
    sys.exit("Error: League name was not set!!")

leagueNameId = sys.argv[1]

ladder = testapi.ladder.retrieve(leagueNameId, True)

print ladder

for i, val in enumerate(ladder):
    print val['character']['name']
```

`print lader` work ok and I see all printed without any problem but when `print val['character']['name']` I got error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "getevent.py", line 16, in <module>
    print val['character']['name']   File "J:\Program Files\Python2.7\lib\encodings\cp852.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-22: character maps to <undefined>
```

I work on Windows 10 with Python 2.7.12
How it is possible that before `for` loop all is printed ok but after when I try to print some fragments then I got described error?

Answer (score 3):

Printing lists displays the `repr()` of its content, which shows non-ASCII characters as escape codes.  Printing the content directly encodes it to the terminal, which in you case appears to be a Windows console with a default code page of 852.  That code page doesn't support one or more of the characters being printed.

Example (with my default 437 code page):

```
>>> L = [u'can\u2019t']
>>> print L
[u'can\u2019t']
>>> print L[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

But if you change to a terminal encoding that supports the character, with `chcp 1252`:

```
>>> L = [u'can\u2019t']
>>> print L
[u'can\u2019t']
>>> print L[0]
can’t
```

By the way, if you thought `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` would have any effect on printing output, it doesn't.  It declares the encoding of your source file only, and only matters if you have non-ASCII characters in your source.